# Dynamically add HtmlEditorExtender to update panel

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

there is problem with Ajax toolkit control when they arr added dynamically to update panel.
i have test user control ( UC_Test.ascx) and inside it there is a Textbox with HtmlEditorExtender :

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UC_Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="UC_Test" %>
<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="textbox1" CssClass="textbox" Height="40px"/>
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="textbox1"></asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

on the another control there is update panel which contains two elemen(button & PlaceHolder)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text="Add" runat="server" OnClick="button_click" />
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the code behind for button click event is :

```
protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/UC_Test.ascx"));

    }
```

Now, when the button is clicked the control(UC_Test) will be addedd to placeholder in ajax mode successfully but the resource of HtmlEditorExtender(css files and images) did not loaded.
i make a snapshot form the added control :

[image: AjaxToolKit HtmlEditorExtender problem, when it added dynamically to update panel]

as you see the image, the icon for htmlEditorExtender (such as copy,paste , ...) was not laoded.!

Comment: How about placing the HtmlEditorExtender at design time inside a client side <div>, and using Html styles to make the div visible/non visible?

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround for this problem. Place an invisible panel on your master page in between your scriptmanager and the first updatepanel and put a dummy text field and HtmlEditorExtender inside of it. This will make the HtmlEditorExtenders of dynamically loaded controls render correctly.

Apparently the extender needs to load certain resources on first load. The dummy on the master page will make those resources available for extenders created thereafter.

Solution posted by [t010t](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/t010t) on [ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27181).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a year old however I had this same issue. In my case there was a CSS class being applied globally to all buttons.

it was the following.

```
background: #666666;
```

The Firefox firebug plugin showed this had the result of rendering the css as.

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e6e6e6;
```

When I would disable this line of css the buttons would show up. In order to fix this problem I had to change.

```
background: #666666;
```

to

```
background-color: #666666;
```

After this the buttons rendered correctly. This may not solve everyone's problem. But in some cases it may.